# How to select all data with query LIKE in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

Why can not I use '%' or '' in LIKE query builder to select all data?

I try in SQL shell can, but in query builder can not

My Model

```
public function ajax_getTargetMhs($where,$where2) {
        $this->db3->SELECT("nim,nama,kodeunit")
                    ->FROM("akademik_ms_mahasiswa")
                    ->LIKE('kodeunit',$where)
                    ->LIKE('periodemasuk',$where2);
        $query = $this->db3->get();
        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }
```

My Controller

```
public function getTargetMhs($where,$where2) {
        $json =$this->Survey_Model->ajax_getTargetMhs($where,$where2);
        $arr = array();
            foreach ($json as $results) {
            $arr['data'][] = array(
                   $results->nim,
                   $results->nama,
                   $results->kodeunit
                    );
            }
         //save data mysql data in json encode format       
          echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

I can't access like this

```
'ajax': "<?php echo base_url(); ?>survey/getTargetMhs/"+'SINF/'+'%',
```

Comment: show  what u have done  so far

Comment: question was updated

Comment: Your db3 methods should not be uppercased

Comment: because i use 3 db in my program

Comment: are 'SINF' and '%' are passed parameters?

Comment: yes sir........

Comment: Why would you use that in the where clause? If you leave where clause out, it will select all rows.

Comment: Clause where not work to select all data, where always need data spesific

Comment: Looks like you are building an url `"<?php echo base_url(); ?>survey/getTargetMhs/"+'SINF/'+'%',` but % is used to encode characters in urls. You need to properly escape data you put in urls.

Comment: how to escape?.

Answer (score 0):

The method `like()` accepts a third parameter that describes which "side" of the "matching" string to put wildcard characters on. Acceptable values are 'none', 'left', 'right', 'both'.

If you don't pass a "side" value then 'both' is used. Not sure which is the correct choice for you. If you want to construct the whole matching argument yourself then 'none' should work.

Documentation on `like()` [HERE](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)